# Plotly for javascript: date language other than english

Tags: plotly, date-formatting, plotly.js

I'm using plotly to create charts. The x axis contains dates. The names of the months are in english but I want them in dutch.

This is a simple example of what I do with plotly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My chart page</title>
        <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.20.0.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
    
    <script>
       var trace1 = {
          x: ['2023-05-01', '2023-05-02', '2023-05-03'],
          y: [20, 14, 23],
          name: 'apples',
          type: 'bar'
        };

        var trace2 = {
          x: ['2023-05-01', '2023-05-02', '2023-05-03'],
          y: [12, 18, 29],
          name: 'oranges',
          type: 'bar'
        };

        var data = [trace1, trace2];

        var layout = {
            barmode: 'stack',
            xaxis: {
                tickformat: "%b %d",
                dtick: "D1"
            },
        };

        Plotly.newPlot('root', data, layout);
    </script>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to change the language used for the month names?

In addition: the hover text also contains the month names in english.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but if anyone lands here looking for more info,
From Plotly: For more time formatting types, see: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md

https://plotly.com/javascript/tick-formatting/

```
var layout = {
    title: 'Time series with custom tickformat',
    xaxis: {
      tickformat: '%d %B (%a)\n %Y' // For more time formatting types, see: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md
    }
  };

  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By lack of any other solutions I will post here two options that I found.

### Edit plotly

The first option is to download the plotly library and edit it. Replace all month name strings with those of the language you want. Then include the local copy in the webpage. The benefit of this option is that it also changes the language of the hover text.

### Custom axis labels

The second option is to use custom axis labels. For the example above that would be:

```
xaxis: {
    fixedrange: true,
    tickmode: 'array',
    tickvals: ['2023-05-01', '2023-05-02', '2023-05-03'],
    ticktext: ["1 mei", "2 mei", "3 mei"],
},
```

The drawback of this approach is that it doesn't change the language of the hover text. Also, it requires a fixed range on the axis. More precise, you could have an editable axis range but it would not have labels besides those you specified.